# hidesBarsOnSwipe doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios8

**Have a following structure:**

`UIViewController` (*VC*) with some `UIViews`(*views*) on the top half of screen and `UITableView` (*tableView*) on the bottom half of screen. All are on the same hierarchy level within *VC's* view.

*VC* is managed by `UINavigationController`.

Auto-layout is off. Using autoresizing masks.

`dataSource` and `delegate` methods are set up and works fine.

**What I want to realize:**

Hide a navigation bar when scroll up and show in after the scroll down.

**What I did:**

Since my project supports iOS8+ only, just setting:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
}
```

should be fine.

**What I have:**

1. Swiping up and down on the views hides and shows navigation bar respectively.
2. Scrolling tableView makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spent some time on that and found that resizing tableView to make it match to vc's view solves the problem.

**Edit:**

1. Is it mentioned somewhere in the docs that table view should be only full screen?
2. Found interesting thing: even if you didn't set `hidesBarsOnTap` to `YES` and try to tap on navigation area (i.e. when it's still hidden after swipe) - navigation bar will show after that. Very annoying if you have any UI elements in that area.

Comment: This works for WKWebView's as well. Thanks for the tip.